# Trying to run a motor with Brick Pi 3

Tags: raspbian

I am using Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ and a BrickPi board. I have also modified installed Raspbian OS by following the steps mentioned in https://www.dexterindustries.com/BrickPi/brickpi-tutorials-documentation/getting-started/pi-prep/

After this step, I have connected the motor and tried to test the motor by running the motor_sensor.py

The following error is coming up:

```
pi@raspi001:~ $ python motor_sensor.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "motor_sensor.py", line 7, in <module>
    BrickPiSetupSensors()
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/BrickPi.py", line 492,
     in BrickPiSetupSensors
  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/BrickPi.py", line 698,
     in BrickPiFlush
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py",
     line 572, in inWaiting
    return self.in_waiting
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py",
     line 456, in in_waiting
    s = fcntl.ioctl(self.fd, TIOCINQ, TIOCM_zero_str)
IOError: [Errno 25] Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

motor_sensor.py script is as follows:

```py
from BrickPi import *

BrickPiSetup()

BrickPi.MotorEnable[PORT_A] = 1

BrickPiSetupSensors()

BrickPi.MotorSpeed[PORT_A] = 200

BrickPiUpdateValues()
```

I do not know what to do.

Comment: There is not enough context to see the problem.  Could you edit your question and add the `motor_sensor.py` script?